# Why python Phonenumbers library give null for country of +358*****?

Tags: python, phone-number

I use the below code to get the country of phone number and I currently use `phonenumbers`:

```
query = phonenumbers.parse(number, None)
geocoder.country_name_for_number(query, "en")
```

It gives error for numbers with `+358`. The library version I tested was the latest: `7.4.4`

Anyone has a solution or workaround with this library? The country should be `Finland`

---

**EDIT1:**
For example the below number gives an empty string:

```
>>> number = '+358753263000'
>>> query = phonenumbers.parse(number, None)
>>> geocoder.country_name_for_number(query, "en")
u''
```

Comment: string vs int problem?

Comment: Does it have the correct number of digits for Finland phone numbers?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, it correctly outputs "Finland" for me.

Comment: @Barmar the number is `+358753263000`

Comment: @L3viathan, what version do you use?

Comment: @AlirezaHos The latest one. It doesn't work with your phone number, but it does with an invented one that is one digit shorter.

Comment: @L3viathan, these are numbers purchased on a real platform! I've just changed the last numbers to mask it.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Finland) show the proper format for Finland phone numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You may have *overmasked* it. As @Barmar pointed out, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Finland), the numbers after the '+358' the next number should be 9 (or 0).

```
>>> geocoder.country_name_for_number(phonenumbers.parse('+358753263000'), 'en')
u''
>>> geocoder.country_name_for_number(phonenumbers.parse('+358953263000'), 'en')
u'Finland'
```

Changing that first number from `7` to `9` gives Finland. You also have too many digits but it doesn't seem to mind.

Comment: I just masked last 4 numbers: `3000`. As I said before my tests are on a real numbers not masked ones. I just masked it here for display purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the prefix `+358` is ambiguous. You can see that if you call

```
>>> geocoder.region_codes_for_country_code(358)
('FI', 'AX')
```

`+358` is the prefix both for Finland and for the Åland Islands (AX).

If a code is ambiguous, `country_name_for_number` then [checks all](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers/blob/dev/python/phonenumbers/geocoder.py#L74-L104) of the regions and calls `is_valid_number_for_region` for the specific number. If it finds that the number is valid in more than one region, it returns an empty string.

Comment: For my number which is a full number and of course valid and in use, what solution I should take?

Comment: Maybe open an issue on the Github page?

Comment: I think I have to!

Answer (score 0):

I have opened an issue on their `github` page:

[Why python phonenumbers library return empty string for country of +3587*****?](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/issues/1198)

In case there was an answer, I would post it here later on.